# webscraping the current page in its current state

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping

ive webscraped before using beautiful soup by making a html request.

but now i dont want data from say wikipedia,i want data from something after it has been modified by the user. eg teslas website has this feature https://www.tesla.com/en_gb/models/design#battery where you personalize your car. suppose i wanted to open this page, change the settings from long range to high performance and THEN grab the inner html from

```
<span class="specs--value">
```

(how long it takes to go from 0 to 60)

how could i do this. write a script in python/c# which can grab data from the browser i currently have open, using what tools can i gather data from my current browser

ideally this will be for google chrome

edit:
alternate idea. perhaps i could make a post request which somehow recieves html data as if i did click on the high performance button. but how could i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use selenium, It allows to simulate user navegation and extract data during the process.